# Inherited Null Pointer Exceptions (Java)

Tags: java, regex, nullpointerexception

In a program I am writing I have the following code to create a regular expression for a word and retrieve all words that match it from a series of different ArrayLists.

```
public ArrayList<String> solveWord(String str)
{
    String regex = "";
    String[] strArr = str.split("");
    for (String temp : strArr)
    {
        if (temp.equals(" "))
        {
            regex = regex + "[a-z]";
        }
        else
        {
            String s = "[" + temp + "]";
            regex = regex + s;
        }

    }
    int x = str.length();
    ArrayList<String> m = null;
    System.out.println("2ns");
     switch (x) 
     {
     case 1:  break;
     case 2:  m = let2;
              break;
     case 3:  m = let3;
            break;
     case 4:  m = let4;
            break;
     case 5:  m = let5;
            break;
     case 6:  m = let6;
            break;
     case 7:  m = let7;
            break;
     case 8:  m = let8;
            break;
     case 9:  m = let9;
            break;
     case 10:  m = let10;
            break;
     case 11:  m = let11;
            break;
     case 12:  m = let12;
            break;
     case 13:  m = let13;
            break;
     case 14:  m = let14;
            break;
     case 15:  m = let15;
            break;
     case 16:  m = let16;
            break;
     }   
    System.out.println(" ns");
    ArrayList<String> trans = retrieve(str,m,regex);
    return trans;
}

private ArrayList<String> retrieve(String word, ArrayList<String> arr, String reg)
{
    ArrayList<String> ex = arr;
    ArrayList<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String temp : ex)
    {
        if (temp.matches(reg))
        {
            matches.add(temp);
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```

When I call solve(String str) from another class, the line "strArr = str.split(""); throws a null pointer exception. The other problem I am having is that when I test this class on its own, the line if(temp.matches(reg)) gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character     class near index 12
[][h][a-z][h]
            ^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.String.matches(Unknown Source)
at Words.fillInTheBlanks.retrieve(fillInTheBlanks.java:238)
at Words.fillInTheBlanks.solveWord(fillInTheBlanks.java:228)
at Words.tester.main(tester.java:12)
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: What is the value of `str` when it throws exception?

Comment: It varies as its being used as part of a crossword generator to fill the the down clues. So in this case its something like "h u e"

Comment: That in itself should work fine. Can you post the call stack you get when nullpointerexception happens?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Words.fillInTheBlanks.solveWord(fillInTheBlanks.java:175)
 at Words.Crossword.setVerticals(Crossword.java:139)
 at Words.Crossword.solve(Crossword.java:48)
 at Words.tester.main(tester.java:10)

Comment: Well, the only thing that can be null in this line is `str`. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: One thing that has occurred to me, is that my code to update the intersections hasn't worked properly, which would indeed leave str as null.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have empty square brackets `[]` in your regex. You have to check if `temp` is not empty before producing your regex:

```
if (temp.equals(" "))
{
    regex = regex + "[a-z]";
}
else if (temp.length() > 0)
{
    String s = "[" + temp + "]";
    regex = regex + s;
}
```

---

As for NullPointerException, the only possibility of it happening in line `String[] strArr = str.split("");` is that `str` is null.

Answer (score 0):

Here in split function problem is that ; you need to split by using some string and that string can not be like just "" .
If you want to split by space then write " ".

Comment: No, you can split by `""` - this will split into single characters.